# Groovy MetaClass - Add category methods to appropriate metaClasses

Tags: grails, groovy, categories, metaclass, mixins

I have several categories that I use in my Grails plugin. e.g.,

```
class Foo {
    static foo(ClassA a,Object someArg) { ... }
    static bar(ClassB b,Object... someArgs) { ... }
}
```

I'm looking for the best way to add these methods to the meta-classes so that I don't have to use the category classes and can just invoke them as instance methods. e.g.,

```
aInstance.foo(someArg)

bInstance.bar(someArgs)
```

Is there a Groovy/Grails class or method that will help me do this or am I stuck iterating through the methods and adding them all myself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Groovy 1.6 a much simpler mechanism for using categories/mixins was introduced. Previously the methods of a category class had to be declared static, and the first parameter indicates which class of objects they could be applied to (as in your `Foo` class above).

I find this somewhat awkward because once the methods of the category are "mixed in" to the target class they are non-static, but in the category class they are static.

Anyway, since Groovy 1.6 you can do this instead

```
// Define the category
class MyCategory {
  void doIt() {
    println "done"
  }

  void doIt2() {
    println "done2"
  }
}

// Mix the category into the target class
@Mixin (MyCategory)
class MyClass {
   void callMixin() {
     doIt()
   }
}

// Test that it works
def obj = new MyClass()
obj.callMixin()
```

A few other features are available. If you want to restrict the classes that the category can be applied to, use the `@Category` annotation. For example, if you only want to apply `MyCategory` to `MyClass` (or it's subclasses), define it as:

```
@Category(MyClass)
class MyCategory {
  // Implementation omitted
}
```

Instead of mixing the categories in at compile-time using `@Mixin` (as above), you can mix them in at runtime instead using:

```
MyClass.mixin MyCategory
```

In you're using Grails, `Bootstrap.groovy` is a place where you might do this.